# Remove zero th index from php array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

i have an array $items . it has certain elements like Array([0]=>1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ72q.png)=>2 [2]=>3) . from this array i can able to remove the first and second index . but i can't remove the 0 th index using array unset method.

is there is any way to remove 0th index from array?

Thanks in advance...

```
<?php
session_start();
$items = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cartitems = explode(",", $items);
print_r($cartitems);
if(isset($_GET['remove']) & !empty($_GET['remove'])){

$delitem = $_GET['remove'];
unset($cartitems[$delitem]);

$itemids = implode(",", $cartitems);

$_SESSION['cart'] = $itemids;

if($_GET['remove']==0)
{

    unset($cartitems[0]);
    $itemids = implode(",", $cartitems);

$_SESSION['cart'] = $itemids;
}

//echo "<script>alert('removed Successfully ');window.location= '".('hide.php')."'</script>";
}



?>
```

i have above code. in that i am getting key(index) from `$_GET['remove']`.so i will unset that particular key from the array. but i can't unset that oth index.
[image]

i can't able to remove the television from the array.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to remove the first element of an array in PHP you can use `array_shift($array)`.

For example:

`$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
 $fruit = array_shift($stack);`

`$stack` will now contain `["banana", "apple", "raspberry"]`, while `$fruit` will be equal to `"orange"`.

Comment: i don't want to shift. i just want to delete 0th index of an array

Comment: That's what shift does? It deletes the 0th (first) index of your array.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `array_shift($array)` to remove first element of array. It will reset the keys and your keys will be changed. So, if you want your keys to be changed, you can use `array_shift($array)`.

If you do not want your keys to be changed, use the following:

```
reset($array);

$key = key($array);
unset($array[$key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `unset` method should work:

```
 <?php 
    $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    print_r($arr); // output [0] => 1 [1] => 2 and so on

    unset($arr[0]);
    print_r($arr); // output [1] => 2 and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

check the if condition you have used
if(isset($_GET['remove']) & !empty($_GET['remove'])) instead use if(isset($_GET['remove']) )

Try this code

```
<?php
session_start();
$items = $_SESSION['cart'];
$cartitems = explode(",", $items);


if(isset($_GET['remove']) ){
$delitem = $_GET['remove'];
unset($cartitems[$delitem]);

$itemids = implode(",", $cartitems);

$_SESSION['cart'] = $itemids;
} 
?>
```